# Why mysql 5.6 is not installing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, mysqldump

I have tried installing mysql server several times but am frustrated because none of the versions has worked. Am getting an error message that "there is an error in XML document (0,0). This installer will now close.

Comment: Welcome. How are you trying to install? You don't say in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to why you are trying to install version 5.6 which was [released 5 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Release_history). Why not 5.7 which was released 3 years ago, or even version 8, which was released 9 months ago.

Assuming that you have good reason, I notice that you said

> I have tried installing mysql server several times

and that might have messed up the registry. Also, IIRC, MySQL like an empty directory to install to.

So, if you can't install a more recent version, I suggest using a good uninstaller - [Revo](https://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html) is the bets that I am aware of -
which will scan the registry and your hard-drives  for any detritus left over from previous, interrupted, install attempts. After that, you will be making a truly fresh install and will hopefully have more success.